# Adding Border To ImageButton

Tags: android, border, adt, imagebutton

I have a simple Android application that uses ImageButtons. I want to put a border around the image whenever the user clicks/selects the button. How can I do this programatically?

[image]

I thought about making separate images (each with a border) then changing the image when the user clicks but I have many images and I want to avoid photoshopping them if at all possible.

UPDATE - here is a snapshot of my layout from Eclipse IDE

[image]

Comment: you can use `<selector>`

Comment: not sure what is <selector> will google it now thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) with two sub views:

- One is the background with a [selector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).
- One is an `ImageView`/ `ImageButton` to display the image.
- By default, if you don't handle click events of the foreground view, the system will transfer them to the background selector, and you handle them there.

---

*Edited*

You should use a [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) then load all images programmatically when the user opens your activity, don't hardcode it. For each item of the `GridView`, you can use the above layout I suggest… And just in case you need, this video is worth watching: [Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView](http://youtu.be/wDBM6wVEO70) (`ListView`'s usage is same as `GridView`).

Comment: i am using the eclipse adt and the top level layout looks like it already is a relativelayout. do i need to add another one? (see my original post i added a screenshot of my layout)

Comment: @JanTacci I think that is a `GridLayout`? I mean for each item (image), you can use a `RelativeLayout` with two sub items. This is what I used in my app ([here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haibison.android.apps.files), the icons of the files). And just some words, please use nice English  :-)

Comment: Do you mean add a RelativeLayout to each location where I have a button? If so, can you recommend an easy way to do this in Eclipse ADT without messing up my images?

Comment: @JanTacci I'm sorry for `GridLayout`. I think it would be `GridView`, I edited the answer. I think the YouTube video is good, it's about an hour, please give it a try if you have time. In the past someone on SO helped me start with it  :-)

Comment: do you mean GridLayout or is GridView something different? (sorry i am  new to all this!)

Comment: @JanTacci You can keep the root view (`RelativeLayout` as your code), then replace the `TableLayout` with a `GridView`.

Comment: ok, reading about grid views now. i guess with a grid view I need to add the components in code not using the Eclipse UI.